# What are the letters near the monsters name?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

What are the letters near the monsters name on FFXIV such in this picture? Do they have an specific keybind or they`re merely aesthetic for tagging?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, they're for tagging to make it easier to clarify which enemy you're targeting (this is primarily useful in groups against raid content, obviously). The letter keeps looping a-z while the group structure you're in remains unchanged; joining a group or adding a new member to the group resets the count.

(Not 100% sure about the last one; will test it out when I get home, assuming the server lets me in...)

Comment: I can confirm, these are simply assigned to help your group coordinate. Also, the little gems to the left are aggrometres: red means the monster is targeting you, flashing yellow means it's losing interest, everything else means you better use those taunts.

Comment: Oh, neat. Didn't know that yet.